# Java: Find any String in a Document

Tags: java, regex

I'm really bad at regex so i hope you can help me:

I've written a class which can open a `odf` document, search for some given `keywords`(the `keys` in a `hashmap`) and *replace* these keywords with content of other `odf-files` (values of the hashmap). The class is finished so far, just the regex part is missing. Everything works if the keys are just strings like "FILE" or "REPLACETHIS".
But I also need to be able to replace Strings like "{{File_1}}", "", "!replace this!" and so on. These Strings can be chosen by the user, so the possibilities are endless.
These strings can also be part of other strings, for example: "this is so[replace this]me text".

I hope you understand what i wand and that this is even possible.

-e-
and yes, i have to use regex because the library i'm using needs a Pattern.compile object

Comment: `I'm really bad at regex` so am i and many others, but please show us what you have tried so far .

Comment: I thnk you're going to have experiment with (1) making your keys regex patterns and working on applying to the document in a search.  (2) making your hashmap values regex and applying regex replaces.  Along the way, you'll get better with regex.  There's no shortcut around getting comfortable enough with regex to make this work.  But instead of feeling like you've got to get good at regex all at once, start experimenting and incrementally building your level of comfort.

Comment: ok you got me. Actually i have no idea about regex but i'm realy willing to learn it, right after i've finished learning RoR.

Comment: why not use `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Patern.quote(yourStringToBeReplaced));`? You find all the information in [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: the problem is that the ones who use these class (which is part of a end-user sw) aren't familiar with regex

Comment: @jlordo is correct, you would get the user input and then put it in the code he gave you. what's the problem?

Comment: my answer was directed to DWright. jliordo is correct, thank you very much. I should have read the Doc ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the shortest way to do what I think you want to do is (you confirmed it in the comments below the post):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(yourStringToBeReplaced));
```

This way, characters will *lose* their special regex meaning and the user can input anything they want.

Read more about those methods in [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand (please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) your main problem are characters which have special regex meainings. Why not just escape those characters before compiling the pattern?

```
myPattern = "some user defined word with { strange characters";
myPattern = myPattern.replaceAll( "\\{", "\\{" );
myPattern = myPattern.replaceAll( "\\}", "\\}" );
myPattern = myPattern.replaceAll( "\\.", "\\." );
...
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile( myPattern );
```

Comment: Why do it manually if there are ready ways to do it like using \Q...\E or as jlordo pointed `Patern.quote(yourStringToBeReplaced)` :)

Comment: I have to admit that I am not familiar with those special classes. Thanks for the point.

Comment: Have you even tried it prior to posting? Your replacing won't change the string at all. You would need `myPattern.replaceAll( "\\{", "\\\\\\{" );` to get what you want. That's why `Pattern.quote()` is much easier.

Comment: JavaDoc of `replaceAll()` says: _Note that backslashes (\\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired._